# String of bytes into an int

Tags: python

I want to convert a string like this into an int: `s = 'A0 00 00 00 63'`. What's the easiest/best way to do that?

For example `'20 01'` should become `8193` (2 * 16^3 + 1 * 16^0 = 8193).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `int()` with either `str.split()`:

```
In [31]: s='20 01'

In [32]: int("".join(s.split()),16)
Out[32]: 8193
```

or `str.replace()` and pass the base as 16:

```
In [34]: int(s.replace(" ",""),16)
Out[34]: 8193
```

Here  both `split()` and `replace()` are converting  `'20 01'` into `'2001'`:

```
In [35]: '20 01'.replace(" ","")
Out[35]: '2001'

In [36]: "".join('20 01'.split())
Out[36]: '2001'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> s = 'A0 00 00 00 63'
>>> s = s.replace(" ","")
>>> print s
A000000063
>>> for i in xrange(0,len(s),4):
        print int(s[i:i+3],16)

2560
0
99
```